# How to get the identifier of a contact programmatically

Tags: xdb, experience-profile

In Sitecore 8 it used to be very simple to get the identifier of a contact in code, with this method "contact.Identifiers.Identifier".

This seems to be no longer the case in Sitecore 9. Does anyone have an example of how i can get the identifier of a contact in Sitecore 9 programmatically?

Comment: Did you get chance to have a look at https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/contacts/contact-identifiers.html

Answer (score 3):

In Sitecore 9 you can have multiple identifiers.

On Sitecore.XConnect.Contact you have the following property:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A collection of identifiers associated with the contact. A contact can have zero
    //     or more identifiers.
    public IReadOnlyCollection<ContactIdentifier> Identifiers { get; }
```

Using **contact.Identifiers** you get all the identifiers and you can parse and get one of them depending on your requirements.